# How to handle failed JQuery DOM conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a common function to display errors as a result of an AJAX call. Some of those messages are HTML strings, which I want to convert to a DOM object then search for elements inside it using .find(). Others will be just strings (not HTML). In this case, I don't know how to handle this...it is generating exceptions.

```
var messageTest = "" + this;
if ($(messageTest).length == 0) {
    message += this;
} else {
    message += $(messageTest).find('.message-error').html();
}
```

FYI, "this" in this case seems to be a String object with an array in which each item is a character, so in the inspector, it isn't showing "my message here" but:

```
[0]: "m"
[1]: "y"
```

etc

When it is just a string, which is not HTML, I get an error at the if statement line:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:<The contents of messageText>
```

So how to I gracefully handle this when the input could be an HTML string or just a string?

Note...in the end, I just want the string, as I am going to wrap it in it's own HTML.

Comment: Why do you want to append an empty string to this.. This should do right `var messageTest = this;`

Comment: @Sushanth--that was my hack to get the String object's primitive value...but since found you can do eval(this.valueOf())...haven't tested it yet though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's either a string or HTML, it can always be appended to an element, and then sorted out:

```
var msg = $('<div />').append(this),
    err = msg.find('.message-error'),
    txt = err.length ? err.text() : msg.text();

message += txt;
```

append the string or HTML to an empty div, if the div contains a `.message-error` element, get the text of that element, otherwise get the text of the div, which would equal the original string etc.

Comment: @adeneo-- You rock! That is perfect and clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way, very close to what you have, is to catch the exception, and in this case consider it's a string (assuming `this` contains the response string):

```
var messageString = this;
var messageDOM;
try {
    messageDOM = $(messageString);
} catch(ex) {
    // If we got here, messageString is not HTML
    messageDOM = $('<div/>').text(messageString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but I feel like what you're wanting can be better accomplished by a slight change in methodology.

If you have control of the server sending these responses, i would recommend sending them back as JSON objects, if you make every result a JSON object then you can set an error property to true/false in the object that comes back along with a message value with your HTML or error message.

This is faster on the client system as well since its a native object to javascript and jquery has excellent JSON support using $.getJSON.